# Windows Server 2016 ReFS. Change parity from dual to single

Tags: windows-server-2016, storage-spaces, refs

I have setup five of the same hard drives as a single storage pool using ReFS with  dual parity. I have since decided that space trumps redundancy and would like to convert the volume to single parity to free up the space of an extra hard drive.

Can this be done from the Server Manager without destroying the volume and starting over and if so how?